# Can dagger producer dynamically/recursively generate a tree structure?

Tags: dagger-2

For example, my tree is:

```java
class TreeNode {
  List<TreeNode> children;
}
```

I'm looking for/hoping to have something in producer like:

```java
@ProducerModule
class RecursiveModule {
  @Produces
  ListenableFuture<TreeNode> produceNode(/*...?*/) {
    // Somehow recursively get a node.
  }
}
```

So that it can dynamically parse some external source, and construct a node, recursively, for me.

A more concrete little example use case may be to build a HN news reader. In their [API](https://github.com/HackerNews/API) there is an `Item` that may have multiple children `Item`s. So to read a news item with all comments, one needs to fetch the root `Item` and recursively fetch its children.

*I'm new to dagger producers, and I'm trying to learn what it can do. I'm not sure if this recursiveness breaks the "acyclic" in dagger's name, but I'm curious to see whether this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I (kinda) have a workaround:

Let the component have the production executor passed in as a parameter.

```java
@ProductionComponent(/* ... */)
class TreeComponent {
  // ...
  @ProductionComponent.Builder
  interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    Builder executor(@Production Executor executor);
    @BindsInstance
    Builder id(@NodeId int id); // Say we need an id to know which node to process, or how to process a node.
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then for each node, process the node itself, and create one producer per child.

In this way I'm managing the producer tree myself. But the producer library still takes care of the async coordination. I think there is still benefit to it.